# Removing columns of some data frames in R

Tags: r, subset

I want to remove columns A and B from some data frames. But all my data frames do not have the same columns. For example, df1 has columns A, B and C, so:

```
df1 <- subset(df1 , select = -c(`A`,`B`))
```

But df2 has columns A and D and does not have column B, so I can do:

```
df2 <- subset(df2 , select = -c(`A`))
```

Since I have many data frames, is there a way to change the first code that is also usable for the second df without getting the error that column B is not in the second data frame?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `setdiff`

```
setdiff(names(df1), c('A', 'B'))
```

It can be passed within the `subset` 'select' argument

```
subset(df1, select = setdiff(names(df1), c('A', 'B')))
```

---

It can be wrapped in a function and used for multiple datasets

```
fsubset <- function(dat, colstoRemove){
    subset(dat, select = setdiff(names(dat), colstoRemove))
}


fsubset(df1, c("A", "B"))
fsubset(df2, c("A", "B"))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10, C = 11:15)
df2 <- data.frame(A = 1:6, D = 11:16)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `subset(df1, select = setdiff(names(df1), c('A', 'B')))` instead of `subset(df, select = -c(A, B))`? Is it faster or more robust?

Comment: @tyluRp using the setdiff approach prevents an error occurring if cols A or B do not exist in the dataframe concerned, which is what the OP wanted. What an elegant solution this is!